# How to build a Rails REST API with 2-legged OAuth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, oauth, rspec, 2-legged

I've been struggling for two days with OAuth and RSpec to get a properly tested RESTful API using a 2-legged OAuth authentication so I thought about posting it here and prevent more pain to happen.

So here it is, in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've built an example app. See it there : https://github.com/jerefrer/oauth-two-legged-restful-api